# unable to save record which is created through vf page

Tags: apex, controller

I have created vf page for new record creation of custom object. when i click to new button i am gettting vf page where based on case field value (i.e. CaseNumber)  i am able to prepopulate other fields till this everything is working fine. But i am not able to save that new record. it is not showing me any error, after clicking on save button of vf page it stucked there only.

is there any changes i have to do in controller :

```
public class Populate {
    public Case cs{get;set;}
    public SC_Problem_Management__c prblm{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}

    public Populate(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        cs = new Case();
        prblm = new SC_Problem_Management__c();
        prblm = (SC_Problem_Management__c)controller.getRecord();
        //Get the ID of Currently present case on vf page
        String csId = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id =: prblm.Case__c].Id;
        System.debug('testing'+ csId);
        prblm.Case__c= csId;
        if(csId != null)
        {
            //calling autofilling method
            autoCal();
        }
    }

    //function is called from actionsupport event

    public void autoCal() {
        Id caseid = prblm.Case__c;     // collecting case id from visualforce page
        List<Case> caseLst = [select id,Products__c,Componet__c ,Feature__c,Status,Priority,Subject,Description__c,Assignment_Group__c from Case where id=:caseid];

        if(caseLst.isEmpty())
        {
            return;
        }    
        prblm.Product__c = caseLst[0].Products__c;      
        prblm.Component__c = caseLst[0].Componet__c; 
        prblm.Feature__c = caseLst[0].Feature__c;
        prblm.Status__c = caseLst[0].Status; 
        prblm.Priority__c = caseLst[0].Priority; 
        prblm.Title__c=caseLst[0].Subject;
        prblm.Issue_Escape__c=caseLst[0].Assignment_Group__c;
        prblm.Description__c= caseLst[0].Description__c;
    }
public pagereference Save() 
{ insert prblm;
 pagereference pr = new pagereference('/'+prblm.id); 
return pr; 
}
}
```

vf page :

```
<apex:page standardController="SC_Problem_Management__c" extensions ="populate">

   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
           <div align="Center"><apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons></div>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
            <apex:outputField label="Problem ID" Value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Name}"/>
            <apex:outputField label="Owner" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.OwnerId}"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Product" style="width: 150px; height: 20px"  value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Product__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Primary CI" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Primary_CI__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Component" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Component__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Affected CI Count" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Affected_CI_Count__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Feature" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Feature__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Root Cause Identified Expected Date" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Root_Cause_Identified_Expected_Date__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Status" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Status__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Problem Resolution Expected Date" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Problem_Resolution_Expected_Date__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Impact" style="width: 150px; height: 20px"  value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Impact__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Estimated No. of Man Days" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Estimated_No_of_Man_Days__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Urgency" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Urgency__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Estimated Cost" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Estimated_Cost__c}" />    
            <apex:inputField label="Priority" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Priority__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Revised Release Train" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Revised_Release_Train__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Release Train" style="width: 150px; height: 15px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Release_Train__c}" />
            <apex:inputField label="Case" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Case__c}" />
         </apex:pageBlockSection>   


             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Problem Details" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField label="Title" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Title__c}" />
                <apex:inputField label="Description" style="width: 300px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Description__c}" />
             </apex:pageBlockSection>

             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Assignment Details" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField label="Issue Escape" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Issue_Escape__c}" />
                <apex:inputField label="Assignee" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Assignee__c}" />
             </apex:pageBlockSection>

             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Resolution Details" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField label="Root Cause Description" style="width: 360px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Root_Cause_Description__c}" />
                <apex:inputField label="Corrective Measures" style="width: 360px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Corrective_Measures__c}" />
                <apex:inputField label="Preventive Action" style="width: 360px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Preventive_Action__c}" />
                <apex:inputField label="Workaround for Incident" style="width: 360px; height: 20px" value="{!SC_Problem_Management__c.Workaround_for_Incident__c}" />
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you trying to save `prblm` record in `autoCal()` method? If not, how is the `save` method implemented and being called from the VF page?

Comment: for saving record i am using std command button "Save" on vf page.

Comment: How is that implemented? I don't see a `save` method in your controller. If you are using custom controller, you will need to provide a `save` method implementation here. Can you [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/249261/edit) and provide the VF page code as well?

Comment: @JayantDas i have added the vf code

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `save` method in the extension and putting some debug logs to see if the values are passed appropriately or not?

Comment: @JayantDas i have added save method in controller, while saving getting below error :   Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Product]: [Product]
Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page newproblem: Class.Populate.Save: line 47, column 1

Comment: Please edit your question with these additional details. It seems that there is a field which is required thus causing this error.

Comment: it is showing me error on product field but i have already assigned value to that field in autocal method.

Comment: And is that populated?

Comment: yes it is populate on vf page.

Comment: @JayantDas i am to resolve that issue not problem is added to case. I am facing other issue, i have use this vf page to override new button on problem object, so whenever i click new button to create problem (not through case) it is showing me error as  : " List has no rows for assignment to SObject " please suggest.

Comment: Because the Case__c field is not populated on a new record

Comment: Yes that is right Eric. I figured out the root cause bt unable to fix it. Could you please suggest me, if Case__c field is not provided then how to display the whole vf page where user can manually create problem through tab instead of through case.

Answer (score 0):

As per your latest comment, for this visualforce page to work for new records which are created from tab and not from Case's related list, you will have to add additional check in your controller.

So your controller code should look like this

```
//Get the ID of Currently present case on vf page
if(prblm.Case__c !=null){
    String csId = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id =: prblm.Case__c].Id;
    System.debug('testing'+ csId);
    prblm.Case__c= csId;
    if(csId != null)
    {
        //calling autofilling method
        autoCal();
    }
}
```

Few more suggestions in the code

```
//Get the ID of Currently present case on vf page
if(prblm.Case__c !=null){
    //There is no need for this query as you are getting the Case ID using SOQL with Case ID in where clause
    //String csId = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id =: prblm.Case__c].Id;
    String csId = prblm.Case__c;
    System.debug('testing'+ csId);
    //no need to set the value again to Case__c as it would be already prepopulated when creating using Case's related list
    //prblm.Case__c= csId;
    if(string.isNotBlank(csId))
    {
        //calling autofilling method
        autoCal();
    }
}
```